# Authorize button when Linking Variable Group to Azure Key Vault in Azure DevOps is not working - why?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

I am trying to link Azure Key Vault secrets to a variable group in Azure Pipelines (part in Azure DevOps). Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#link-secrets-from-an-azure-key-vault).

However, the "Authorize" button does not seem to work. It spins endlessly. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJIC5.png).

My target Azure Key Vault already has the service principal included in its access policy with Get and List permissions. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHncd.png).

Anyone seen this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This workaround also seems like a bug for Azure Key Vault deployments using ARM templates.

If the service principal in question is added to the Azure Key Vault (AKV) access policies through an ARM template **by referencing the service principal's Object ID** ([as Microsoft documentation calls for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/2018-02-14/vaults#AccessPolicyEntry)), permission errors with Azure Pipelines follow.

However, if I manually add the service principal to the AKV's access policies **by referencing the service principal's application (client) ID**, the permissions errors go away entirely.

Again, feels like a bug. And now my automated deployment pipeline doesn't quite work because of this manual step.

[image]

Also, in the AKV ARM template, if I were to combine the mandatory field objectId with the optional field applicationId, the service principal shows up as a "compound identity". That does **not** fix the permissions issues in Azure Pipelines. I do not see a way of adding a service principal properly without doing it manually.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please make sure the service connection is working correctly. Then refresh the page and try it again. Alternately you can also try in browser inprivate session.

Just as the message said "`The specified Azure service connection needs to have "Get, List" secret management permissions on the selected key vault.`"

Basically, we need to click the "`Authorize`" button to enable Azure Pipelines to set these permissions for the specific service connection.

If that doesn't work, we can also manually set the permissions for the specific service connection.

1. Go to **Project settings** - > **Service connections** -> Select the
   specific ARM service connection
2. Click **Edit** to popup the **Update Authentication for xxx** dialog
3. Click the "`use the full version of the service connection dialog.`"
   link, to get the `Service principal client ID`
4. Go to your **key vault** in Azure portal -> **Access Policies** -> Add a new
   Access Policy -> Select a template (e.g `Key&Secret Management`) - >
   Select `Get, List` for **Secret  permissions**.
5. Click **Select Principal** -> Copy and paste the `Service principal client ID`
   to search the user/application -> Select the searched
   user/application
6. After that you can see the new **APPLICATION** access policy.

   Try it again after successfully adding the application access policy.

---

**UPDATE:**

Generally in Azure DevOps we need to create a [ARM service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#create-a-service-connection) (the client which can access the azure sources) first before deploying an Azure Key Vault through an ARM template.

Actually when you select the `Azure subscription` then click `Authorize` in [Azure resource group deployment task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops)
, the ARM service connection is created automatically. You just need to check the `AppID` and get the `ObjectID` to use in the ARM template.

We can get the `Service principal client ID` (**AppID**) by following above steps. After that we can get **ObjectId** by the AppID with running the following command: (See [Find service principal object ID using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/find-identity-object-ids#find-service-principal-object-id-using-powershell) for details.)

```
$(Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "AppId eq 'a89c3dee-f5bf-4ea1-a805-d4c729a4add3'").ObjectId
```

Then you can specific the **ObjectId** when deploying the Azure Key Vault through an ARM template.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response Andy. A couple of things:
1. In step 5/6, where you manually add a service principal to the access policy of the Key Vault, you're selecting that service principal through its application (client) ID. However, when deploying an Azure Key Vault through an ARM template, that service principal is supposed to be selected using its object ID. Which one should it be? Does it make a difference? Reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/2018-02-14/vaults#AccessPolicyEntry).

Comment: Also 2. My Key Vault already has the service principal, through its Object ID, included in its access policy with Get and List permissions. [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/YbTA1R7.png).

Comment: @CharlieBrown Yes, we need to create the service connection first, then get the application (client) ID of the service principal. That means we need an existing ARM service connection before using the ARM template.  Actually when you select the `Azure subscription` then click 'Authorize', the service connection is created automatically. You just need to check the `AppID` and get the `ObjectID` to use in the ARM template. See the updated answer for details.

Comment: Thanks again for your response Andy. Given the answer I provided to my own question, it doesn't seem like specifying the Object ID in an ARM template for an existing service principal works. Seems like a bug honestly.